# Updating my js canvas project to React.js Issue with math.pow() for onclick detection that didnt exist previously

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

So its a really simple little game.
An array of 25 circles is made. They bump around the screen.
You are supposed to be able to click on them and they will pop or disappear from the screen.

It all seemed to work fine when i made in in plain js. Now im trying to intergrate it with my react project.

The onclick function no now longer work. I checked all the coords and they are logging fine.

i assume the issue is with the 'Math.pow(algae.radius, 2)' or a line like that in my eventlistener. Because if i change that line to 'Math.pow(algae.radius, 4), the on click function works but is too far outside of the radius.

```js
function EnemyArray() {
  const useScript = (url) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      let canvasBgColour = `#00f000`;
      let algaeColour = `#000000`;

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const container = document.querySelector('#game-container');

      container.appendChild(canvas);

      var rect = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
      canvas.width = rect.width;
      canvas.height = rect.height;

      // Draw canvas
      context.fillStyle = canvasBgColour;
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // Mouse size
      let mouse = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        radius: (canvas.height / 90) * (canvas.width / 90),
      };

      // Mouse position
      container.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        mouse.x = e.x;
        mouse.y = e.y;
      });

      // Listen for clicks
      // If click hits an enemy. They run the 'clicked()' function
      canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

        enemySwarmArray.forEach(function (algae) {
          if (
            Math.pow(x - algae.xpos, 2) + Math.pow(y - algae.ypos, 2) <
            Math.pow(algae.radius, 2)
          ) {
            console.log('PPP');
            algae.clicked();
          }
        });
      });

      // Class Definition for enemy moving around the canvas
      class Algae {
        constructor(id, xpos, ypos, radius, colour, count, speed) {
          this.id = id;
          this.xpos = xpos;
          this.ypos = ypos;
          this.radius = radius;
          this.colour = colour;
          this.count = count; // Number of instance in the array
          this.speed = speed; // Moving speed
          this.clicked = function () {
            console.log('CLIIIIIIICKED', this);
            this.delete(); // Remove enemy from array
          };
          this.dx = 1 * this.speed;
          this.dy = 1 * this.speed;
        }

        // Draw algae on canvas
        draw(context) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.strokeStyle = this.colour;
          context.lineWidth = 4;
          context.textAlign = 'center'; // Data in center of algae
          context.textBaseline = 'middle';
          context.font = '20px Arial';
          context.fillStyle = this.colour;
          context.fillText(this.count, this.xpos, this.ypos); //
          context.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);
          context.stroke();
          context.closePath();
        }

        // Movement
        update() {
          this.draw(context);

          // Detect collisions
          if (this.xpos > canvas.width) {
            this.dx = -this.dx;
          }

          if (this.xpos - this.radius < 0) {
            this.dx = -this.dx;
          }

          if (this.ypos > canvas.height) {
            this.dy = -this.dy;
          }

          if (this.ypos - this.radius < 0) {
            this.dy = -this.dy;
          }

          this.xpos += this.dx;
          this.ypos += this.dy;
        }

        // Delete algae on click
        delete() {
          console.log(
            'Enemy died later in hospital, his widow was told he survived and then had her heart broken twice.'
          );
          //   const foundAlgae = enemySwarmArray.find((a) => a.id === this.id);
          //   const algaeIndex = enemySwarmArray.indexOf(foundAlgae);
          //   console.log('foundAlgae', algaeIndex);
          //   enemySwarmArray.splice(algaeIndex, 1);
        }
      }

      let totalSizeOfAlgaeArray = 25; // Number of enemies to create
      let enemySwarmArraySize = 1; // Current number of enemies
      let enemySwarmArray = []; // Store enemies created here
      let hitCount = 0; // Enemies Hit

      if (enemySwarmArraySize < totalSizeOfAlgaeArray) {
        // Create enemy array
        for (let i = enemySwarmArraySize; i < totalSizeOfAlgaeArray; i++) {
          console.log('enemySwarmArray', enemySwarmArray);
          let random_x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
          let random_y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
          const newEnemy = new Algae(
            i,
            random_x,
            random_y,
            20,
            'red',
            enemySwarmArraySize,
            1
          );
          newEnemy.draw(context);

          enemySwarmArraySize++;
          enemySwarmArray.push(newEnemy);
        }
      }

      // Redraw each frame of the screen
      function updateSwarm() {
        requestAnimationFrame(updateSwarm);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        enemySwarmArray.forEach((algae) => {
          algae.update();
        });
      }

      function run() {
        updateSwarm();
      }

      run();
    }, [url]);
  };

  return (
    <div id='game-container' className='grid absolute w-full h-full'>
      {useScript()}
    </div>
  );
}
```